# Solvability by radicals of Polynomials defined by a recurrence relation

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, radicals, solvable-groups

I want to determine the smallest integer $m$ such that the polynomial $P_{n}(x)$, $n\geq m$, given by :
$$\left \lbrace \begin{array}{l}
P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x) (x-n-1) + \prod\limits_{i = 0}^n x-i\\
P_0(x) = 1
\end{array} \right.$$
is not solvable by radicals.

Let $E$ be the set of all roots of $P_n(x)$ and $\mathcal{G} = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(E)/\mathbb{Q})$. I know that $P_n(x) = (-1)^n P_n(n-x)$ and :
$$\forall \alpha \in E, 0<\alpha<n.$$

So I deduced :

1- $$\lvert \mathcal{G}\rvert = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor -1} n -i -2k,$$
with $n\equiv i\ mod(2)$. So $8\leq m$.

2- $\exists \sigma \in \mathcal{G}, \forall \alpha_j \in E \rvert \sigma(\alpha_j) = \alpha_{n-j-1}$, with $0\leq j < n$. I ordered the roots such that $\alpha_j < \alpha_{j+1}$.

Is it correct (I am new in Galois Theory)? Can we say more about $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: I have checked for $P_n(x)$ where $n \leq 61$ that all polynomials for $n \geq 10$ are not solvable. Additionally checked for _selected_ small $n$ size of Galois groups of their roots and found that only in case $P_8(x) = 9x^8-288x^7+3822x^6-27216x^5+112245x^4-269136x^3+354372x^2-219168x+40320$ the size is different than proposed: 192 ($[2^3]S(4)$) instead of the proposed 384.